# Code smell - if/else construct

Tags: python, oop, code-duplication

I have a list of 9 elements. The first three represent positions, the next velocities, the next forces.

Sometimes I require forces from the array, other times velocities, and other times positions.

So I wrote a function as follows:

```
def Extractor(alist,quantity):

    if quantity=='positions':
        x = alist[0]
        y = alist[1]
        z = alist[2]
        return (x,y,z)

    elif quantity=='velocities':
        vx = alist[3]
        vy = alist[4]
        vz = alist[5]
        tot_v = np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2 + vz**2)
        return (vx,vy,vz,tot_v)

    elif quantity=='forces':
        fx = alist[6]
        fy = alist[7]
        fz = alist[8]
        tot_f = np.sqrt(fx**2 + fy**2 + fz**2)
        return (fx,fy,fz,tot_f)
    else:
        print "Do not recognise quantity: not one of positions, velocities, force"
```

However, this seems like a massive code smell to me due to duplicate code. Is there a nicer, more pythonic way to do this? I'm quite new to OOP, but could I use some kind of class inheritance utilising polymorphism?

Comment: Create three functions.

Comment: By the way, uppercased names like `Extractor` are usually used for classes, not for functions. This is a convention, not a requirement, but using it will allow people to read your code more easily.

Comment: You can consider using `x, y, z = alist[0:3]` so reduce code size.

Comment: Is it good to have all these values in the same array? It seems like it forces you to do unnecessary work, unless there's some benefit to it that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your method violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Consider splitting it like this:

```
def positionExtractor(alist):
    return tuple(alist[0:3])

def velocityExtractor(alist):
    velocity = tuple(alist[3:6])
    return velocity + (np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in velocity)),)

def forcesExtractor(alist):
    forces = tuple(alist[6:9])
    return forces + (np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in forces)),)
```

You can put them in a dictionary:

```
extractors = {
    'position' : positionExtractor,
    'velocity' : velocityExtractor,
    'forces' : forcesExtractor}
```

and use:

```
result = extractors[quantity](alist)
```

---

Here is an example with inheritance. It seems to be over-engineering for such a simple task though:

```
import numpy as np

class Extractor:
    def extract(self, alist):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class IndexRangeExtractor(Extractor):
    def __init__(self, fromIndex, toIndex):
        self.fromIndex = fromIndex
        self.toIndex = toIndex

    def extract(self, alist):
        return tuple(alist[self.fromIndex:self.toIndex])

class EuclideanDistanceExtractorDecorator(Extractor):
    def __init__(self, innerExtractor):
        self.innerExtractor = innerExtractor

    def extract(self, alist):
        innerResult = self.innerExtractor.extract(alist)
        distance = np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x in innerResult))

        return innerResult + (distance,)

#... 

class ExtractorFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.extractors = {
            'position':IndexRangeExtractor(0, 3),
            'velocity':EuclideanDistanceExtractorDecorator(
                IndexRangeExtractor(3, 6)),
            'forces':EuclideanDistanceExtractorDecorator(
                IndexRangeExtractor(6, 9))}

    def createExtractor(self, quantity):
        return self.extractors[quantity]


alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ef = ExtractorFactory()
e1 = ef.createExtractor('position')
e2 = ef.createExtractor('velocity')
e3 = ef.createExtractor('forces')

print e1.extract(alist)
print e2.extract(alist)
print e3.extract(alist)
```

Comment: I have posted working code for this that illustrates this below.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by using an offset to pick out the elements; all but `positions` need a formula applied too:

```
_slices = {'positions': slice(3), 'velocities': slice(3, 6), 'forces': slice(6, 9)}

def Extractor(alist, quantity):
    try:
        a, b, c = alist[_slices[quantity]]
        tot = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2)
        return a, b, c, tot
    except KeyError:
         raise ValueError(
             "Do not recognise quantity: "
             "not one of {}".format(', '.join(_slices)))
```

This returns a *consistent* number of values; if calculating the square root for `positions` is not possible, I'd return `0.0` for the total:

```
tot = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2) if quantity != 'positions' else 0.0
```

Comment: Though this reduced the size a bit, the `offset` is by nature meaningless and not beautiful at all.

Comment: @Ray: Yeah, I contemplated using `itemgetter()`, then didn't, and now Jon has a solution using it anyway. I'll use slices here instead.

Comment: @Ray: There, that's better anyway, with a exception handler for the quantity not being recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something like this:

```
    def extract_position(x,y,z):
        return (x, y, z)

    def extract_velocities(x,y,z):
        return (x, y, z, np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2))

    def extract_forces(x,y,z):
        return (x, y, z, np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2))

    extractor = { 'positions': extract_position,
                  'velocities': extract_velocities,
                  'forces': extract_forces }

    try:

        print extractor['positions'](1,2,3)

        print extractor['unknown'](4,5,6)

    except KeyError:
        print "Do not recognise quantity: not one of positions, velocities, force"
```

I prefer to use function pointers to tie data to arbitrary calculations. Also, the dictionary replaced the switch style syntax so this at least feels similar to what you were looking for.

Also you have the same calculation for determining velocities and forces, so you could condense that as well.

Comment: The whole purpose of `extractor` was to *extract* elements from lists. Your function `extract_position` for example doesn't do anything interesting - you can group three variables into a `tuple` without a dedicated function. Thus (and for some other minor reasons) this example doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The point was that he should change how he is storing the information that he is processing. My example separates the two.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea, but in this form these functions don't make any sense. And their names are misleading - they don't extract anything. This example can be easily reduced to just one function: `euclideanDistance` that calculates the last element of the resulting `tuple`.

Comment: @brandonsimpkins You may have missed the fact that the OP's function is "extracting" three values from a list of _nine_. Yours take three arguments and return all three, which makes less sense.

Comment: As I said before, he obviously is unclear on how to clean up the processing. I'm sure that his data structure of a list of 9 integers is equally as confusing. He should also look to change that, but changing the data structure was outside the scope of his question.

Comment: I don't have any control over the data structure - it's what I get when I extract a line from an output file produced using a molecular dynamics simulation program that I didn't write.

Comment: You do have control over the data structures you use. You do not necessary have control over the inputs that get passed into your script. But you can map those inputs to a more meaningful data structure. I can post a concise example if you wish.

Comment: @brandonsimpkins That's exactly what OP's code is intended for probably - mapping the inputs to a more meaningful data structure...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def extract(sequence, quantity):
    try:
        a, b, c = {
            'positions': itemgetter(0, 1, 2),
            'velocities': itemgetter(3, 4, 5),
            'forces': itemgetter(6, 7, 8)
        }[quantity](sequence)
        return a, b, c, np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2, c**2)
    except KeyError as e:
        pass # handle no suitable quantity found here
```

Note that a calculation is always performed instead... keeps the return value consistent as a 4-tuple... unless it's a *really* expensive calculation, this shouldn't be an issue.